# Ask power series convergence issues

Tags: analysis

I have a good understanding of Hadamard rule. But I have a poor understanding of the corollary of Hadamard: the power series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j (x-c)^j$ has radius of convergence $\rho$ if and only if, when $0<R<\rho $, there exists a constant $0<C=C_R$ such that $|a_j| \leq \frac{C}{R^j}$

The textbook uses this example: the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{3^j}{j^2+1} x^j$ satisfies $|a_j| \leq 3^j$. It follows from the corollary above that the radius of convergence of the series is $1/3$.

I don't understand this example, though I can work it out if I use Hadamard rule instead (i.e., to find lim sup). But this example seems that in this case, $C=1, R=1/3$, but then how do you know $\rho$ is $1/3$?

Comment: I don't know what *exactly*  you do call Hadamard rule to, but we have Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem, which states that in the case fo the power series $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n\;$ , its convergence radius $\;R\;$ is given by $$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$ Using the above is how I'd get the radius of convergence $\;1/3\;$ in your example

Comment: Yes, I just mean this rule. Now the textbook also discussed the corollary of the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem.

Comment: Again, I don't know what corollary you mean, but we know that for any  number $\;\rho<R\;$ s.t. $\;|x-c|\le\rho\;$, we get absolute and uniform convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$$

Comment: Corollary: the power series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j (x-c)^j$ has radius of convergence $\rho$ if and only if, when $0<R<\rho $, there exists a constant $0<C=C_R$ such that $|a_j| \leq \frac{C}{R^j}$

Comment: That corollary seems to be pretty trivial, and I can't seem to understand how useful can it be...Basically they're using comparison with a convergent geometric series.